# How to save the state of Multiple checkbox using a Button click

Tags: java, checkbox, android-recyclerview

In my App I have a `recyclerView` of `ArrayList` in which i setted a `checkBox` next to the textView. what i want to save the state of  the `checkBox` by clicking a button, and i want to load it in another activity , and these all should done with the `SharedPrefrennces`.

Actually I am not getting the concept that how can i save the state of `checkBox` in `SharedPrefrennces` by clicking button.

**NOTE**:Please keep in mind i am begginer

Here is the code that shows what i did ..

```
public class StudentListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String DATETIME = "dateTime";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter rAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<ListOfNames> listOfNames;


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

String t1 = "10";
String t2 = "100%";
Bundle bundle;
String subName;
Toolbar toolbar;
boolean[] items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_list);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    subName = bundle.getString("Subject Name");
    if (bundle != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(subName);
    }
    loadData();


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());


    toolbar.setSubtitle(currentDate);
    fabButton();
    buildRecyclerView();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScrollingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("count", listOfNames.size());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.changeDateTime:
            handleDate();

            return true;
        case R.id.pastAttendances:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PastAttendences.class);

            intent.putExtra("Title", subName);
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            String result = sharedPreferences.getString(DATETIME, null);



            intent.putExtra("key", result);

            editor.remove(DATETIME);
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

        case R.id.saveButton:

            final String toolbarDateTime = toolbar.getSubtitle().toString();

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(DATETIME, toolbarDateTime);
            editor.apply();


            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void handelTime(final CharSequence charSequence) {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int Hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int Minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    boolean is24Hour = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int Hour, int Minute) {


            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, Hour);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minute);

            CharSequence charSequence1 = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss a", calendar1);
            toolbar.setSubtitle(charSequence + " " + charSequence1);
        }
    }, Hour, Minute, is24Hour);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

public void handleDate() {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int date) {


            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

            CharSequence charSequence = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MMM-yyyy", calendar1);

            handelTime(charSequence);
        }
    }, year, month, date);

    datePickerDialog.show();
}


private void buildRecyclerView() {

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(StudentListActivity.this);
    rAdapter = new AdapterForStudentList(this, listOfNames);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}

public void insertData(String text, String t1, String t2) {
    ListOfNames lt = new ListOfNames(text, t1, t2);
    if (listOfNames.contains(lt)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Student Name Already exists!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        listOfNames.add(lt);
        rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

public void saveData() {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(listOfNames);
    editor.putString(subName, json);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadData() {


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(subName, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListOfNames>>() {
    }.getType();

    listOfNames = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (listOfNames == null) {
        listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}


ListOfNames deletedItem = null;
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        String name = listOfNames.get(position).getStudentName();

        deletedItem = listOfNames.get(position);
        listOfNames.remove(deletedItem);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("text");


        saveData();
        editor.apply();
        rAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, name + "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        listOfNames.add(position, deletedItem);
                        rAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

                        saveData();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(StudentListActivity.this, R.color.my_background))
                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                .create()
                .decorate();
        super.onChildDrawOver(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

    }
};

public void fabButton() {
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentListActivity.this);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogbox_frontpage, null);

            final EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            b.setView(view);
            b.setTitle("Student name");
            b.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                    if (text.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(StudentListActivity.this, "Please add subject name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        insertData(text, t1, t2);
                        saveData();
                    }
                }
            });
            b.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            b.setCancelable(false);
            b.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**I made changes in the Adapter class for saving the state of the checkbox its working but when i am saving the state of the checkbox then ,what i checked earlier is disappering and when i removed the saving code which is saving my state of checkbox then its working fine the checked box state isnt disappering**

Actually i dont want this i want to save the states of checkbox on a button click  and want to load in a another activity which isnt happing . can you explain. 
I think i described my issue well...

**This is the AdapterClass for above code.**

```
public class AdapterForStudentList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForStudentList.StudentViewHolder> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<ListOfNames> mListOfNames;


public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView studentName, attendence, percentage;
    CheckBox mCheckedBox;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public StudentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        studentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        attendence = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendence);
        percentage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        mCheckedBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCheckBox);
        mCheckedBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic) {
        itemClickListener = ic;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View v, int position);
    }

}

public AdapterForStudentList(Context context, ArrayList<ListOfNames> listOfNames) {
    this.context = context;
    mListOfNames = listOfNames;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public StudentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_box_cardview, parent, false);

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("checkedItems", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean valueBoolean = preferences.getBoolean("KEY", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("KEY", valueBoolean);
    editor.apply();

    return new StudentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    ListOfNames currentItems = mListOfNames.get(position);
    holder.studentName.setText(currentItems.getStudentName());
    holder.attendence.setText(currentItems.getAttendent());
    holder.percentage.setText(currentItems.getPercetage());
    holder.mCheckedBox.setChecked(currentItems.getChecked());


    holder.setItemClickListener(new StudentViewHolder.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;

            ListOfNames currentItems = mListOfNames.get(position);

            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

                currentItems.setChecked(true);

            } else {
                currentItems.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.mCheckedBox.setChecked(getFromSp("mCheckedBox"+position));
    holder.mCheckedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            saveInSp("mCheckedBox"+position, isChecked);

        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListOfNames.size();
}
private boolean getFromSp(String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("checkedItems", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key,false);
}

private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("checkedItems", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Comment: Can anyone plz answer this question

Comment: Have you fixed it yet? Correct me if I'm wrong but you wanted to save the state of the checkbox in SharedPreferences and show said state in another activity?

Comment: No actually i tried so much and i am not able to fixed also i searched it everywhere but i didn't get what i want

Comment: In my activity i have menu item there is a save button i want that when I'll click that it should save the state of checkbox

Comment: Ah, I see. I have just tried your code. There seems to be a bug that when you add another item, the check boxes reset back to false. Does that happen to you?

Comment: Yes it is i said this in my question also

Comment: What are you going to use the check box for? And does the user have the ability to add a new item while still being able to check/uncheck? If so, then it will render your _save_ button in the menu useless. Because when you add a new item, you add it to the list then save it along with the checked items.

Comment: I had written in my question that i have a check box with text next to it and I Want to just save the state of check box from the list and want to transfer the same data with text into another activity  .. And no user will not have ability to add new item while still being able to check /unchecked.... Is it too complicated to just save the state and load it to another activity the same list with checked sate. Actually I'm not getting how to do i used all the concepts but fail

Comment: Are you really getting what I want to do, Am i able to explain my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to use `SharedPreferences` to save the states of the check boxes. You can just use the `setChecked` method inside your `ListOfNames` class.

Also, why you're getting that bug when you add a new item is because the method `onCheckedChanged` of the `CheckBox` listener gets **unnecessarily invoked** when you called `notifyDataSetChanged`. The concept is that when you notify the adapter, <del>it ***recycles***, in other words,</del> it ***recreates*** the views therefore if the check boxes were checked then they turned back to unchecked, it may as well invoke `onCheckedChanged` modifying the previous value. (Note: I remembered that the term *recycle* is different from *recreate*)

One way to deal with this is to use `OnClickListener` instead and get the `CheckBox` from there and see its value.

**So instead of**:

```
holder.mCheckedBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

**Change it to this:**

```
holder.mCheckedBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
        boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
        // ...
    }
});
```

That should solve that strange phenomenon from happening.

Back to using `SharedPreferences`, as I already suggested, use your `setChecked` method of your `ListOfNames` class *(see code below)*. Then remove anything that has to do with `SharedPreferences` inside your adapter.
And because you're not adding new items nor removing then whichever check boxes you check, it won't save until the user presses the save button in your menu. In which, you can just use your `saveData` method of your `StudentListActivity` for the save button.

Also, remove the `ItemClickListener` interface and the `implements View.OnClickListener` inside your `ViewHolder`. It's pretty redundant.

Your `AdapterForStudentList` should now look like this:

```
public class AdapterForStudentList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForStudentList.StudentViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ListOfNames> mListOfNames;

    public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView studentName, attendence, percentage;
        CheckBox mCheckedBox;

        public StudentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            studentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
            attendence = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendence);
            percentage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.percentage);
            mCheckedBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mCheckBox);
        }

    }

    public AdapterForStudentList(Context context, ArrayList<ListOfNames> listOfNames) {
        this.context = context;
        mListOfNames = listOfNames;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StudentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_box_cardview, parent, false);
        return new StudentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ListOfNames currentItems = mListOfNames.get(position);
        holder.studentName.setText(currentItems.getStudentName());
        holder.attendence.setText(currentItems.getAttendent());
        holder.percentage.setText(currentItems.getPercetage());
        holder.mCheckedBox.setChecked(currentItems.getChecked());

        holder.mCheckedBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
                boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
                currentItems.setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListOfNames.size();
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** Do not forget to implement constraints that will prevent the user from adding or removing items. It's not that there will be a grandiose exception, rather, it will make your save feature *futile*.

Also, I had the impression that you wanted to be able to add/remove items while also being able to check/uncheck the check boxes. <del>The solution I came up with is *to create another list that holds the positions of the checked check boxes* then use it when the user taps on the save button.</del> (See updated post below) That should give you both the ability to add/remove and check/uncheck whilst also not saving the checks yet until the user does so. (If you want this, I can make the code and put it here)

Last thing, if you *do put* the constraints then I see **no problem using `OnCheckedChangedListener` instead** of the implementation I did above because I don't feel like you will be calling `notifyDataSetChanged` anywhere else other than when an item was added/removed.

Hopefully I clarified something.

---

**Update: Implement both the ability to change the list and the ability to only save the check boxes' states on user action**

The solution I gave you earlier to create a list to put the positions of the checked items is **not actually a good idea**. What if we remove from the list? Or even worse, what if we sort the list?

This is I think the best approach: **create a transient variable that holds the temporary state of the check box and only pass its value when the user taps on save.** Transient variables don't get serialized/included in the json string when we convert it using `Gson`.

So inside your `ListOfNames` class, I suggest creating that said transient variable. And use that for temporary checking/unchecking. Only save it to `SharedPreferences` when the user actually wants to.

**Your `ListOfNames` should look like this:**

```
public class ListOfNames {
    // variables...

    // Create a transient variable to hold the temporary state of the check box
    private transient boolean tempChecked;

    // constructor and other methods...

    // Couple of methods for operations on temporary checks and actual checks
    public void setTemporaryChecked(boolean checked) {
        tempChecked = checked;
    }

    public boolean getTemporaryChecked() {
        return tempChecked;
    }

    public void checkedToTemporaryChecked() {
        tempChecked = checked;
    }

    public void temporaryCheckedToChecked() {
        checked = tempChecked;
    }
}
```

**Inside the listener for the `CheckBox` in `onBindViewHolder`:**

```
// Get the temporary checked value instead of the actual one
// (Because you know, RecyclerView recycles views)
holder.mCheckedBox.setChecked(currentItems.getTemporaryChecked());

holder.mCheckedBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
        boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
        // Set the temporary checked instead
        currentItems.setTemporaryChecked(isChecked);
    }
});
```

**Inside your `loadData` method:**

```
public void loadData() {
    // ...

    // Set our temporary checks
    // Important because transient variables don't get included in Json string
    for (ListOfNames current: listOfNames)
        current.checkedToTemporaryChecked();
}
```

**Finally inside your save logic code in the menu (*NOT INSIDE* your `saveData` method):**

```
case R.id.saveButton:
    // ...

    // Convert temporary checks to actual checks
    for (ListOfNames current: listOfNames)
        current.temporaryCheckedToChecked();
    saveData();

    return true;
// ...
```

And there done! You should be able to add, remove or even sort the list (if you want to add this feature later on) without affecting the check boxes and also save those check boxes' values only when the user does so.

Comment: Yes i want to be able to add /remove items and able to check/uncheck boxes.. But the main thing I'm not getting how can i save it when user click on Save button and can it be loaded in another activity

Comment: This app is a Attendance taker so when I'll take the attendance I'll check the boxes and I'll save it and I'll update the save list to another activity... And if I want to add some names to the list so I'll add... I think These two things are different

Comment: I updated my post. Along the way, I figured out that what I suggested you before was not a good idea. (That putting checked positions in a list) Because a lot of code will be involved and I don't like that. Anyway, I hope this solves what you want to implement now.

Comment: It's solved the problem ☺️, i never heard about transient variable before but it makes easier to save and load the data